# spring socket convertandsendtouser with external message broker(RabbitMQ) in cluster environment

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-websocket

Spring will append sessionid to destination queue for external message broker like RabbitMQ. I noticed this sessionId for username is fetched from DefaultUserSessionRegistry ->userSessionIds.

Will it work in cluster environment? If it is not being fetched from DefaultUserSessionRegistry, where is this mapping stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, in a clustered environment, this may not fully work at the moment.

You probably want to track [the SPR-11620 issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11620), targeted for Spring Framework 4.2.

Comment: Can we avoid this issue by making each user to subscribe to his own queue like /topic/notification-username, where username is the unique to user.And at the sending side use convertandsend instead of convertandsendtouser so that message reaches single user and we avoid need for UserSessionRegistry .Is this good solution?

Comment: the issue is now complete and available in master; did you try with 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT ? It's available here: http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/.